# Application unable to communicate with port listening on same container when Istio is installed

Tags: istio

I have a container running in a pod that runs several jars on different ports. Specifically it is running a java application and an Artemis server.

The application talks to the Artemis server via rpc.

All works fine until I install Istio and inject a sidecar. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas how Istio could be affecting communication within the container/pod.

Comment: How did you install istio? Has you enabled mTLS by default? Before installing Istio, which platform were you using? kubernetes, openshift, etc?
Did you create a Service for that pod?

Comment: @Sean O;Reilly Were you able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already injected sidecar into your Pod or a particular namespace, that means that so far Istio [Envoy proxy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#envoy) will take care of traffic management actions, such as i.e. intercepting incoming and outgoing calls for the nested Kubernetes services. Therefore, communication between microservices will be under Istio Control plane responsibility as per Istio [Architecture](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#architecture) aspects.

Generally, Istio represents its own resources for traffic management purposes. These have to be used in order to establish secure connection to the targeted microservices:

> There are four traffic management configuration resources in Istio:
>   VirtualService, DestinationRule, ServiceEntry, and Gateway:
>
> - A    [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService)    defines the rules that control how requests for a service are routed    within an Istio service mesh.
> - A    [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#DestinationRule)    configures the set of policies to be applied to a request after    VirtualService routing has occurred.
> - A    [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#ServiceEntry)    is commonly used to enable requests to services outside of an Istio    service mesh.
> - A    [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Gateway)    configures a load balancer for HTTP/TCP traffic, most commonly    operating at the edge of the mesh to enable
>     ingress traffic for an    application.

I encourage you to learn more about Istio mesh features with some good [Examples](https://istio.io/docs/examples/) as well.